# External JSON to create/update node

Tags: 8

I have external REST service with some info about products. This comes from some software of the company.

How I can use this JSON I got to create nodes and fill in the fields in nodes?

Also, I need to detect when something is changed and to update field in existing node.

I'm on Drupal 8 and I'm getting JSON with POST method (I need to send 'id' parameter in order to get product for exact client).

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some code with what you're trying to do? Also, is it necessary to post the request or can you make a GET request? The call for the data would be handy to see too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Feeds Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) does this great for D7, offering cron imports and ability to update existing nodes/etc. Looks like they have a D8 branch, but I haven't tested. Might be helpful to look at for you.